# How to fake guzzele post request to get response data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

In laravel i need to fake guzzlehttp post request.

```
        try {
            return $client->request('POST', $url);
        } catch (GuzzleException $e) {
            return $e->getCode();
        }
```

this request return 401 or success message with some data.

At the moment i need to fake this to call some other methods. How can I do that?

This is the part of my composer file

```
"laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0.0",
```

Comment: fake it where? in a testing method?

Comment: @HCK : nope in a controller. purpose to do that is to get a response from that URL. URL is not defined yet.that is why i need to fake it

Comment: oh ok, check @gordon's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [Guzzle docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html):

> Guzzle provides a mock handler that can be used to fulfill HTTP requests with a response or exception by shifting return values off of a queue.
>
> ```
> // Create a mock and queue two responses.
> $mock = new MockHandler([
>     new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']),
>     new Response(202, ['Content-Length' => 0]),
>     new RequestException("Error Communicating with Server", new Request('GET', 'test'))
> ]);
>
> $handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
> $client = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);
>
> // The first request is intercepted with the first response.
> echo $client->request('GET', '/')->getStatusCode();
> //> 200
> // The second request is intercepted with the second response.
> echo $client->request('GET', '/')->getStatusCode();
> //> 202
> ```

Also:

> Guzzle ships with a node.js test server that receives requests and returns responses from a queue. The test server exposes a simple API that is used to enqueue responses and inspect the requests that it has received.

If the MockHandler and the testing webserver don't suffice, consider writing your own Handler. See http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/handlers-and-middleware.html#handlers for details.

Comment: This works for GET request. can you suggest for POST request. Great btw.

Comment: @Deemantha afaik the http method is irrelevant. the mock handler will accept anything.